# Modify Active Directory attribute max length

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'd like to change the max length of the *department* attribute from 64 to 150.

Is it wise to modify core active directory attributes? or should I create another attribute with my length requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you got a complex environment I would add another attribute if you can.

As you can change the rangeUpper of it (from 64), usually it's safe but it can impact third part product. As some applications expect the default value and will give you an error after.

Like an example [there](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/3b1b835e-3388-4c56-be1c-890191c05382/can-i-modify-department-attribute-without-any-issue?forum=winserverDS) with the Set-Mailbox cmdlet from Exchange 2010 after someone changed the rangeUpper from 64 to 96for the department;

> Set-Mailbox -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $true -Identity xyz
>
> error:
>
> The length of the property is too long. The maximum length is 64 and
>   the length of the value provided is 65. Property Name: Department

You could change the [cmdlet after](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2016/05/19/get-the-source-code-of-the-powershell-cmdlets/) to make it work.. but it can be a lot of work.

Try to test it in lab before is the best advice I can give you.

*For reference, as you state the default value is 64; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675490(v=vs.85).aspx*